# Cordova Plugin Creation using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cordova-plugins

I created kind of Apple Map application using Swift. The app which i was created I need to do in Cordova ,So i planned to create a swift plugin in Cordova and want to launch this map using plugin.

Swift Apple Map :

Viewcontroller.swift I used only MKMapView, MKCircle, MKPolyline,

Method for rendering :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer 
{}
```

Method for Custom Annotation update :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? 
{}
```

While I tapping the button from Cordova project, I need to showcase the swift apple map inside Cordova project is it possible ?

If its possible can you please suggest some tutorial.

I tried some earlier tutorial like "Cordova Plugin" But it is not helped for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on how to develop a Cordova plugin in Swift for iOS and recently updated that to cover Swift 3 and XCode 8.2.  You may need to update your code to use `@obcj` to tell the compiler what name to use to expose your Swift functions to Cordova which remains Objective C.  My updated tutorial can be found [here](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios-e314acf68a47#.1xxihldrj).

Comment: The link to your tutorial is giving a 404 error